# Как проверить флажок если он не нажат

Tags: javascript, input

Я сделала мини тест на js, на язык не обращайте внимания, в `value` находятся баллы, если правильно угадал то добавляется 1 балл.

```js
var Div = document.getElementsByClassName("textOut")[0];

function f1() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("color");
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].type == "radio" && input[i].checked) {
      var a1 = input[i].value;
      var a2 = Number(a1);

    } else {
      a2 = 0; //если input не нажат, тогда ответ будет равен нулю.
    }
  }
  var result = a2;
  Div.innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="color"/><i></i><span class="answer">Zelená</span></label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" value="0" name="color"/><i></i><span class="answer">Červená</span></label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" value="0" name="color"/><i></i><span class="answer">Černá</span></label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" value="0" name="color"/><i></i><span class="answer">Nevím</span></label><br/>
<button onclick="f1()">Výsledky</button>

<div id="output"><span class="textOut"></span></div>//Тут будет количество набранных баллов
```

Я хочу что бы когда я не выбрала никакой из вариантов, или же выбрала но не правильный, в диве `output` был ноль, точнее ноль баллов, ноль там конечно появляется, но когда я делаю Правильный выбор, в диве `output` всё равно появляется число 0, а должно было 1. Как это решить и в чем моя ошибка? Благодарю за ранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант попроще вашего :

```js
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("textOut")[0]

function f1() {
  // ищем нужный нам "отмеченый" инпут
  const selected = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked')
  // выставляем значение в диве, если отмеченого инпута нету, то 0
  div.innerHTML = selected ? selected.value : 0
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="color"/><i></i><span class="answer">Zelená</span></label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" value="0" name="color"/><i></i><span class="answer">Červená</span></label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" value="0" name="color"/><i></i><span class="answer">Černá</span></label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" value="0" name="color"/><i></i><span class="answer">Nevím</span></label><br/>
<button onclick="f1()">Výsledky</button>

<div id="output"><span class="textOut"></span></div>//Тут будет количество набранных баллов
```

```js
const div = document.getElementsByClassName("textOut")[0]
const names = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')]
  .map(e => e.name)
  .filter((v, i, s) => s.indexOf(v) === i)

function f1() {
  let result = 0
  names.forEach(n => {
    // ищем нужный нам "отмеченый" инпут
    const selected = document.querySelector(`input[type="radio"][name="${n}"]:checked`)
    // выставляем значение в диве, если отмеченого инпута нету, то 0
    result += selected ? +selected.value : 0
  })
  div.innerHTML = result
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="color"/><i></i><span class="answer">Zelená</span></label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" value="0" name="color"/><i></i><span class="answer">Černá</span></label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" value="0" name="color"/><i></i><span class="answer">Nevím</span></label><br/>

<hr />

<label><input type="radio" value="0" name="radio2"/><i></i><span class="answer">wrong</span></label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="radio2"/><i></i><span class="answer">right</span></label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" value="0" name="radio2"/><i></i><span class="answer">wrong</span></label><br/>

<hr />

<button onclick="f1()">Výsledky</button>

<div id="output"><span class="textOut"></span></div>//Тут будет количество набранных баллов
```

Comment: Благодарю, не знаю почему я ищу тяжелые пути...

Comment: А что если у меня таких инпутов много и они с разными именами? Как их всех добавить в `querySelector`?

Comment: и для каждой группы инпутов, свой див для результата ?

Comment: нет только один, нужно зделать так? `input[name="color"]`

Comment: аааа, кажеться понял, полпробуйте селектор `input[type="radio"][name="color"]:checked`, как вы и написали, но вообще в таких вопросах лучше всего конечно смотреть на разметку)

Comment: Да, я хотела в конце сделать подсчет баллов, а innerHTML только меняет текст в диве, извиняюсь я об этом не сказала...

Comment: @ElviraKukhtaruk добавил небольшой пример, как можно было бы сдеклать подщет при большом количестве груп

Comment: Спасибо вы очень помогли, всё как я хотела)